# Should I apply for a job directly or through a recruiter?

Tags: recruitment, employment

I have applied to a company that I really want to work for directly through their website. I got a reply from the HR saying they will be scheduling interviews next week or two when the hiring manager returns from vacation. Even though they didn't mention anything about scheduling an interview for me, I want to keep high hopes for this.

Today while browsing the jobs, I found the same job posted on a recruiting agency. They don't mention the company, but I immediately identified the opportunity from job description and location.

My question is: Is it wise to apply again through the recruiter for additional exposure and show case my strong interest? Or that will be negatively received?

Comment: Contact the agency to confirm that it is the same job.

Comment: By applying through the recruiter, you would be tacking on a 30% to 40% markup to your salary (that would have to be paid to the recruiter instead of you). Not only that, but you would be muddying the water as to who can get the credit for having found you. So to avoid souring business relationships and potential legal disputes over that commission, your resume would just end up in the trash while the HR person who threw it in there would just be shaking his head saying to himself: "Why the hell did he do that? Why?" and then he'd probably use a bunch of swear words when referring to you.

Comment: And whatever you do, don't contact the agency to see if it's the same job. Anyone can be an independent recruiter these days. All it takes is one phone line and that's it. And the barrier to entry is so low, it's getting pretty competitive. And contacting an independent recruiter who can't even afford to feed himself to tell him that you've applied to a position at a particular company he knows about. That is just asking for trouble. Because unscrupulous recruiters will try to get that commission even if they're not the ones responsible for having earned it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Never EVER apply twice for the same position.  I can tell you from first hand experience that a resume from two sources is 100% of the time rejected.

If you go through a recruiter, they get a fee.  The company is NOT going to get in the middle of any legal wrangling that goes one by getting involved with who gets the finders fee.

They simply blacklist you.

Comment: This is the best way to look at it

Answer (score 6):

Skip the recruiter.  You can negotiate a higher salary if the company doesn't have to pay the recruiter's finders-fee!!!  Also -- since the hiring manager's out, it's likely that you're not going to get anywhere faster by going through the recruiter.